# Problema con Spring Security y AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

Estoy tratando de configurar mi sitio para que omita el inicio de sesión en una vista en AngularJS (mi vista en angular se llama `/validate#/validateusername/`) Pero no he podido conseguirlo, ¿alguna sugerencia de cómo puedo lograr esto?

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
  auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("137").password("user").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/forgotpassword").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/validateusername/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll()
    .and().csrf().disable();
```

Comment: Agrega información de tu controller de angular y quizá del ruteo para que sea mas fácil ayudarte, también tu código de configuración de Spring Security parece estar incompleto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parece que estas confundiendo el manejo de URLs de `AngularJS` del lado del cliente (basado en hashes #) con la configuración de `Spring Security`.

Recuerda que `Spring Security` maneja la seguridad del lado del servidor, mientras que `AngularJs` trabaja en el lado del cliente.

Si sigues en el ambiente de una sola página de `AngularJS` y navegas a otra *página* con un hash(#) en la URL (Checa este [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes)) no estarías haciendo llamadas al servidor.

Lo que haces en realidad es pedirle a `AngularJS` que haga el render de un template o estado diferente.

Eso es comportamiento del lado del cliente, por lo tanto `Spring Security` no está involucrado. Haces llamadas al servidor cuando accedes a un archivo HTML el cual podría ser retornado estáticamente sin autenticación alguna, o por ejemplo si tienes una `REST API` configurada, para obtener datos de tu servidor (tipicamente retornando datos en formato `JSON`).

Yo creo que para que esto funcione los datos para tu recurso protegido (`"/validate"`) no tendrían que estar incluídos en la aplicación principal, requiriendo un recurso del lado del servidor diferente. Esto podría incluir ya sea el archivo HTML para la pagina o los datos. Tu aplicación `AngularJS` debería reconocer que ese recurso no esta disponible y mostrar algun mensaje al usuario para comunicar que no hay permisos suficientes.

Sólo para finalizar, creo que podrías concentrar los permisos más bien en tus `REST APIs` en vez de las páginas mismas, ya que por lo regular las aplicaciones de `AngularJS` funcionan en *una sola página*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]